# Jest error: cannot parse package.json as JSON: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: jestjs, yarnpkg, wsl-2

I just installed jest globally using yarn in WSL2, however when I tested, it gave me this error, can anybody tell me how to fix this?
[image: error]

These are the steps that I followed when was installing it:

```
yarn global bin

yarn config set prefix ~/.yarn
```

Next, I added:

```
export PATH="$PATH:`yarn global bin`"
```

to ~/.bashrc

```
yarn global add jest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I just solved this error by adding the {} bracket to the package.json and it work. Thank you everyone for checking out my question.

Comment: I get this same error if my .json file does not end in a newline